# URL redirect for a site we don't want employees to go to any more

Tags: http

Most of the tools we use are in the cloud.  We are changing one of the tools and want to make sure employees begin using it.   So if a user types in the url:  asdf.tool1.com/login they are automatically redirected to url:  jklg.tool2.com/login

None of these sites are under our control so we have to only use tools like our in house dns or any other option.   I'm aware that DNS can not do this.   Are there any other options?

thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question. What framework are you using? Is this pure html? And incidentally, yes DNS can do this if you redirect the old name to the new IP.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent DNS name redirecting to the new site will only work if tool2 servers accept requests for the tool1.com domain name, or for any domain name, and there's a reasonably good chance they won't.

Answer (score 0):

Add an in-house DNS entry for asdf.tool1.com pointing to an in-house server. Configure the server to accept all connections and reply with a 301 redirect to asdf.tool2.com.